# ¿Cómo hago una consulta para que me devuelva los productos del año pasado hasta ahora?

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva por ejemplo los productos del año pasado hasta ahora en una consulta SQL usando `SYSDATE` en Oracle?

Tendría que pasar `SYSDATE` a otro formato para restarle uno  al año para ponerlo entre el `BETWEEN` y `SYSDATE`, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario reformatear sysdate, puedes utilizar:

```
sysdate-365
```

ó

```
sysdate - interval '1' year
```

Dependiendo de cómo manejarías los años bisiestos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
WHERE CampoFecha between add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) and trunc(sysdate)
```

Le restas doce meses a la fecha actual y haces un between hasta la fecha del sistema.